# How to retrieve username from a message in Quickblox?

Tags: java, android, xmpp, quickblox

I am trying to retrieve the Username of the creator of a Message in Quickblox.

I am able to retrieve the ID of the user with `message.getFrom();` but cannot figure out how to get the username through either using the User ID # or from the message itself. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
chat.addChatMessageListener(new ChatMessageListener() {
  @Override
  public void processMessage(Message message) {

    Log.i("QB LOG", "Message : " + message.getBody());

    //Get userID from message
    int userIdNo = Integer.parseInt(message.getFrom());

    //Would like to be able to retrieve user name here <---
  }

  @Override
  public boolean accept(Message.Type type) {
    switch (type) {
      case chat:
        return true; // process 1-1 chat messages
      default:
        return false;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String from = message.getFrom();
int participantId = Integer.valueOf(QBChatUtils.parseQBUser(from));


QBUsers.getUser(participantId, new QBCallbackImpl() {
@Override
public void onComplete(Result result) {
if (result.isSuccess()) {
QBUserResult qbUserResult = (QBUserResult) result;
Log.i(TAG, ">>> User: " + qbUserResult.getUser().getFullName()
```

Comment: QBCallbackImpl is now depricated please use QBEntityCallback